# Activity Tracker

Tags: c#

estoy desarollando un Activity Tracker para el call center donde trabajo, estoy usando C# para la app de escritorio y Blazor para los informes de actividad, actualmente he logrado captar los movimientos de teclado y mouse con las librerias user32.dll y kernel32.dll.
Lo que no he logrado y sinceramente no tengo idea de como hacer, es ver cuanto tiempo dedica el usuario a las aplicaciones.
he creado el registro de aplicaciones abiertas con algo asi:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process p in processes)
{
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))
  {
    registrar_log(p.MainWindowTitle)
  }
}
```

pero se como identificar en cual proceso tiene el foco o cuanto tiempo dedica activamente a cada proceso.
Agradezco cualquier idea o sugerencia de por donde seguir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esto tendrias que interoperar con los eventos que nos brinda:

- [System.Runtime.InteropServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices?view=net-7.0)

Que tiene dos metodos/ que te pueden ayudar

- [GetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow)

> Recupera un identificador de la ventana de primer plano (la ventana con la que el usuario está trabajando actualmente). El sistema asigna una prioridad ligeramente mayor al subproceso que crea la ventana de primer plano que a otros subprocesos.

- [GetWindowText](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta)

> Copia el texto de la barra de título de la ventana especificada (si tiene una) en un búfer

Tenia un ejemplo en borrador asi que lo deje en un repositorio publico

- Windows Activity Tracker https://github.com/fernandezja/windows-activity-tracker

Captura por ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El titulo del navegador en la ventana/tabs activa
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero hay que ver que esto de estar escuchando con "timer" cada segundo, pueda ser por ejemplo con un evento del sistema operativo que cambia de pantalla. Eso seria mejor

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.